# Determine the square or triangular polynomial closest to a given polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Define the term “closer to” for polynomials in the intuitive way: $B(z)$ is closer to $A(z)$ then $C(z)$ if the degree of $\lvert A(z) \pm B(z) \rvert$ is smaller than the degree of $\lvert A(z) \pm C(z) \rvert$, or the coefficients are smaller in the case the degrees are equal.

Now let's say I have an arbitrary polynomial, *e.g.*
$$
    A(z) := 4z^4-28z^3+60z^2-43z+8.
$$
Is there an algorithm to determine the closest square [or triangular or cubic, *etc.*] polynomial to $A(z)$? For example,
$$
  4z^4-28z^3+60z^2-43z+8 = (2z^2-7z+3)^2-(z^2+z+1),
$$
and so $(2z^2-7z+3)^2$ is the closest polynomial square to $A(z)$. But I know this only because I constructed the example in the first place!

EDIT: Here's a new concrete example. I'm trying to show that $$3x^4+3x^2+1$$ can never be a square. So how can I calculate the nearest square above and below?

Comment: Chebychev polynomials are your (and my) friends.

Comment: A-ha! Thank you for that direction. Quickly scanning http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_theory#Optimal_polynomials shows me the direction I need to search.

Comment: If anyone has a link to a short example or tutorial on exactly how to use Chebychev polynomials to "divide" a polynomial into its largest square and remainder, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @martycohen: Do you have a link or short example on how to use Chebyshev polynomials to show that $(2z^2-7z+3)^2$ is the [polynomial] square closest to $4z^4-28z^3+60z^2-43z+8$?

Comment: This would not involve Chebychev polynomials. Write your polynomial as $4z^4(1-7/z+15/z^2...)$ and then use the expansion $(1+x)^{1/2}=1+x/2-x^2/8+...$ with $x$ being the terms in $1/z$. See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem

Comment: Wolfram Alpha, when given $\sqrt(4 z^4 - 28 z^3 + 60 z^2 - 43 z + 8)$, returns, as part of its answer, $2 z^2 - 7 z + 11/4 - 9/(8 z) + O((1/z)^2)$ as the expansion at $z=\infty$.

Comment: @martycohen: Please make that expansion comment into an answer, so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(at OP's request)

Wolram Alpha,
when given
$\sqrt{4 z^4 - 28 z^3 + 60 z^2 - 43 z + 8}$,
returns, as part of its answer,
$2^2−7+11/4−9/(8)+((1/)^2)$
as the expansion at =∞.

You then have to try
integer values for the
11/4 to see which is closest.

For some reason,
this does not work when given
$(4 z^4 - 28 z^3 + 60 z^2 - 43 z + 8)^{1/2}
$.